# XSLT 1.0 Template and Variable Creation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am running this code, where I am formatting the datetime in '@datetime' according to my needs.
This code works perfectly.

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/call">

    <xsl:variable name="datestr" select="substring-before(@datetime,' UTC')" />

    <xsl:variable name="MMM" select="format-number(string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',substring(substring($datestr,1,3),1,3))) div 3 + 1,'00')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="D" select="format-number(floor(substring($datestr,5,1)),'00')" />

    <xsl:variable name="YYYY" select="substring($datestr,8,4)" />

    <xsl:variable name="hh" select="substring($datestr,13,2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring($datestr,16,2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="ss" select="substring($datestr,19,2)" />

  <!-- <xsl:variable name="DateTimeFormatted" select="concat($YYYY,'-', $MMM, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $mm, ':', $ss, 'Z')" /> -->


Your chat transcript from Univ100 @ Student dated <xsl:value-of select="concat($YYYY,'-', $MMM, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $mm, ':', $ss, 'Z')" />

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/say">

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='customer'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] <xsl:value-of select ="@name" /> says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='agent'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] Student  Officer says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='system'">

<xsl:if test ="./@display ='true'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] System: <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/url">

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='customer'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] <xsl:value-of select ="@name" /> sends:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='agent'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] Student  Officer sends:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='system'">

<xsl:if test ="./@display ='true'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] System: <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/event">

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="parameters"> 



Univ100

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, when I make the following changes, so as to make a different Template for the formatting, which accepts a parameter, and returns the formatted string, so I can use it multiple times as and when required in this Chat Transcript.

I have made the following changes, but the code DOES NOT WORK.

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template name="formatter">
    <xsl:param name="datestr"/>

    <!-- <xsl:variable name="datestr" select="substring-before(@datetime,' UTC')" /> -->

  <xsl:variable name="MMM" select="format-number(string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',substring(substring($datestr,1,3),1,3))) div 3 + 1,'00')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="D" select="format-number(floor(substring($datestr,5,1)),'00')" />

  <xsl:variable name="YYYY" select="substring($datestr,8,4)" />

  <xsl:variable name="hh" select="substring($datestr,13,2)" />

  <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring($datestr,16,2)" />

  <xsl:variable name="ss" select="substring($datestr,19,2)" />

  <!-- <xsl:variable name="DateTimeFormatted" select="concat($YYYY,'-', $MMM, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $mm, ':', $ss, 'Z')" /> -->
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($YYYY,'-', $MMM, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $mm, ':', $ss, 'Z')" />

 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/call">
  <xsl:variable name="returnValue">
    <xsl:call-template name="formatter">
        <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="@datetime"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>

Your chat transcript from Univ100 @ Student dated <xsl:value-of select="$returnValue"/>

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/say">

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='customer'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] <xsl:value-of select ="@name" /> says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='agent'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] Student  Officer says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='system'">

<xsl:if test ="./@display ='true'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] System: <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/url">

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='customer'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] <xsl:value-of select ="@name" /> sends:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='agent'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] Student  Officer sends:  <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test ="./@source ='system'">

<xsl:if test ="./@display ='true'">

[<xsl:value-of select ="@datetime" />] System: <xsl:value-of select ="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/event">

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="parameters"> 



Univ100

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am very new to XSLT 1.0 and I have to work on this as I have no other option to change or upgrade the version, I can only work on Pure XSLT 1.0. This is the only control I have over the project, I don't have access to the DB server, the XML file which uses this XLST or any other aspect of the project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us an example of the XML input and the expected output - see: [mcve]. If you don't have direct access to the XML, use the *identity transform* template to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:value-of select="@datetime"/>` won't invoke your template. Rewrite your "formatter" template to match `@datetime` and then invoke it with `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match="@datetime">
    <xsl:variable name="MMM" select="format-number(string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',substring(substring(.,1,3),1,3))) div 3 + 1,'00')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="format-number(floor(substring(.,5,2)),'00')" />
    <xsl:variable name="YYYY" select="substring(.,8,4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="hh" select="substring(.,13,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring(.,16,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="ss" select="substring(.,19,2)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($YYYY,'-', $MMM, '-', $D, 'T', $hh, ':', $mm, ':', $ss, 'Z')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this template refers to the `@datetime` attribute that it matches with ".", which is x-path short hand for `current()`.

Then update the your other templates to use `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match ="transcript/call">
    Your chat transcript from Univ100 @ Student dated <xsl:apply-templates select="@datetime"/>

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="transcript/say">
    <xsl:if test ="./@source ='customer'">
        [<xsl:apply-templates select ="@datetime" />] <xsl:value-of select ="@name" /> says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./@source ='agent'">
        [<xsl:apply-templates select ="@datetime" />] Student Officer says:  <xsl:value-of select ="." />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./@source ='system'">
        <xsl:if test ="./@display ='true'">
            [<xsl:apply-templates select ="@datetime" />] System: <xsl:value-of select ="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And so on...

Unrelated: I note that your formatter selects the day with `format-number(floor(substring(.,5,1)),'00')`. Is this correct? Does it work for two digit days?

Comment: Thank you very much, this works like a charm!
about the two digit day, thank you for pointing that out, will make changes accordingly.

Comment: could you help me with putting this formatted string into a variable? i tried this:
`<xsl:template match ="transcript/call">`
  `<xsl:variable name="rv">`
    `<xsl:apply-templates select="@datetime"/>`
  `</xsl:variable>`

`Your chat transcript from UP100 @ UP Police dated <xsl:value-of select="$rv" />`

Comment: That looks OK to me. Is it working as you expect? Note that you can just invoke `<xsl:apply-templates select="@datetime"/>` multiple times if you want, rather than using a variable.

Comment: No, unfortunately it isnt. I get
"Your chat transcript from Univ100 @ Student dated "

I have to add a few hours to it, so as to adjust the time from UTC to Local Time zone, I might use string manupilation, so I need the formatted string in the variable...

Comment: If the result is blank it suggests that there is no `@datetime` attribute in the context at the time `apply-templates` is invoked. Try outputting the same select with `value-of` to check that it's present and in the format you expect at that point.

Comment: I did, when I invoke the template, it works perfectly, but when i put that value in a variable, and try to use that variable to show the value, then it shows nothing...

Comment: All I can think of is that your datetime template is returning a nodeset. If this is the case `value-of` will only output the string value of the first node in the set.